# How to retrive the data which was sent to previous deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix, nodejs

I want to access the data which i sent via a function during the previous contract instance . Is it possible to retrieve the data by the the contract instance or transaction hash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to redeploy a contract, if it is already deployed you need to create an instance that point to the contract address

```
async function queryContract() {
    const ContractABI = [...];  // <-- Contract ABI
    const ContractAddress = "0x1234....";           // <-- Deployed contract address

    // Assign deployed address of a contract 
    const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ContractABI, ContractAddress);

    // Send a transaction
    await myContract.methods.sendHash("0x12341234")
    .send({
        from: MyAccount,
        gas: 2000000,
        gasPrice: '30000000000'
    });

    // Query modified data    
    const hash = await myContract.methods.getHash().call();

    console.log(hash)
}

queryContract();
```

Comment: Thank you so much,if i want to get the hash which was sent previously via function to the contract .How do i access it, Is it possible to get via transaction sent?

Comment: To access data in a deplyed contract you need the contract address and the contract ABI. Then you can call any method exposed y the interface. Follow the examples on how to use it from web3 documentation https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html